# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?

Tags: reactjs

I am an Angular Developer and new to React , This is simple react Component but not working

```
import react , { Component}  from 'react';
import         { render   }  from 'react-dom';

class TechView extends Component {

    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           name:'Gopinath'
       }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <span>hello Tech View</span>
        );
    }
}

export default TechView;
```

**Error :**
 'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Answer (score 624, accepted):

The import line should be:

```js
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
```

Note the uppercase R for React.

Comment: how to avoid it. I mean when I create a stateless function, in Nextjs it does not require it

Comment: @MuhaiminCS change the rule in your eslintrc file

Comment: it actualy for older version of React. for newer it not need. right anwere is bellow. by Paul Razvan Berg "rules": {
   ...
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
   ...
}

Comment: but why ? before applying below command it's working export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Answer (score 309):

Add below setting to `.eslintrc.js` / `.eslintrc.json` to ignore these errors:

```
  rules: {
    // suppress errors for missing 'import React' in files
   "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    // allow jsx syntax in js files (for next.js project)
   "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }], //should add ".ts" if typescript project
  }
```

Why?
*If you're using **`NEXT.js`** then you do not require to import `React` at top of files, nextjs does that for you.*

Ref: https://gourav.io/blog/nextjs-cheatsheet (Next.js cheatsheet)

Comment: NextJs user here, thanks for this. 

Given adding the rule `"react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"` will eliminate the error, what does adding `globals` accomplish?  Thanks!

Comment: Note that it'll be "hard" to test your components if React isn't imported, though. In such case, your test file will need to import it, if your component doesn't.

Comment: @GorvGoyl Even after doing this, the build fails with the same error. Any idea how to suppress that?

Comment: This was also relevant for me in a `preact` project. Thank you!

Comment: This became possible in React v17. Official announcement: https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#eslint

Answer (score 98):

If you're using React v17, you can safely disable the rule in your eslint configuration file:

```json
"rules": {
   ...
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks great, small note, I think it's preferable to follow the 0 (off), 1 (warning) and 2 (error) convention over using "off". To keep the config more coherent.

Comment: Choosing either 0 or "off" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Ah I honestly didn't realise all numbers mapped to a string equivalent as well... my mistake. So you can actually do "off, warning, error" or "0, 1, 2".

Comment: Is it safe to disable it in react-native (I'm using the latest version 0.71) !?

Answer (score 68):

For those who still don't get the accepted solution :

**Add**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

**at the top of the file.**

Answer (score 51):

If you are running React 17+ (and in 2022, I assume, that you are) - you need to add the following line to your `.eslintrc`:

```json
{
  "extends": ["plugin:react/jsx-runtime"]
}
```

Then only import React once in your top-level file, like `App.jsx` - and no need to import it anywhere else, unless you need an api like `useEffect` etc.

Comment: I believe this is the most correct answer.

Comment: Only this worked for me on React-Native 0.71.4 and React 18.2, thanks!

Comment: beware that this will make it so eslint doesn't see your ts/tsx files and its hard to debug

Answer (score 16):

**I had the similar issue.**

*Got fixed after i added the code below in the main component: App.js
If you have other components, make sure to import react in those files too.*

```
import React from "react";
```

Answer (score 13):

for me I got this issue once I used `npm audit fix --force` so it downgrade `react-scripts` to version 2 and it forces me to install `eslint` versions 5 and issues started to flood, to fix this I have update it again `react-scripts` and things worked out.
Also make sure that your `eslint` contains those rules

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ['react-app', 'react-app/jest', 'airbnb', 'prettier'],
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  rules: {
    ...
    // React scope no longer necessary with new JSX transform
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    // Allow .js files to use JSX syntax
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': ['error', { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    ...
  },
}
```

Answer (score 10):

add `"plugin:react/jsx-runtime"` to extends in your eslint config file, refer [react-in-jsx-scope](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md#when-not-to-use-it)

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to automate the inclusion of `import React from 'react'` for all files that use `jsx` syntax, install the `react-require` babel plugin:

```
npm install babel-plugin-react-require --save-dev
```

Add react-require into .babelrc. This plugin should be defined before transform-es2015-modules-commonjs plugin because it's using ES2015 modules syntax to import React into scope.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react-require"
  ]
}
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-require

Answer (score 6):

Just import `React` fix this issue:

```js
import React from "react"
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is very straight forward, you imported **react** instead of **React**.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever we make a custom component in React using JSX, it is transformed into backward-compatible JS code with the help of `Babel`.
Since the JSX compiles into **React**.createElement, the `React` library must also always be in scope.

Example:

This custom component:

```js
<MyButton color="blue" shadowSize={2}> Click Me </MyButton>
```

is transformed into:

```js
React.createElement(MyButton, {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2}, 'Click Me')
^^^^^
```

Since the converted code needs the `React` library, we need to import it into the scope.

[React Docs Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type)

> Fix: Import React

```js
import React from 'react';
// or
import * as React from 'react';
```

> Pick one, it depends on the user!

**NOTE:**
As of React 17+, we are free from doing such import, but it's better to add the `imports` just to be on the safe side because errors can be generated because of ESLint!

One can disable the rule in the ESLint config file (`.eslintrc.json`) to ignore these errors:

```
"rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had to include this two-line in my index.js file from the src folder.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

In your case, this might be different.
You may need to include components if you're using class-based components.

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
```

Alternatively, If you are using eslint you can get some solutions from the above comments.

[know more](https://dev.to/chandelieraxel/why-do-react-need-to-be-in-scope-for-jsx-3hen)

Answer (score 4):

When using the react framework, you first need to import the react from react and always keep the first letter of react in uppercase after import.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'`
```

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { render }  from 'react-dom';

class TechView extends Component {

    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           name:'Gopinath'
       } 
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <span>hello Tech View</span>
        );
    }
}
export default TechView;
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I just had to import React.

`import React from 'react';`

Answer (score 2):

This is an error caused by importing the wrong module react from 'react' how about you try this:
**1st**

```
import React , { Component}  from 'react';
```

**2nd** Or you can try this as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render   }  from 'react-dom';

class TechView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           name:'Gopinath',
       }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <span>hello Tech View</span>
        );
    }
}

export default TechView;
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the react-scripts version to latest solved my problem.

I was using the react-scripts version 0.9.5 and upgrading it to 5.0.1 did the job.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I noticed is that import React from "react"; should be there instead of `import react , { Component}  from 'react';`
**Other Things I have done is,**

(1) added below lines to index.js file.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

**if not worked** add this line for `ReactDOM import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";` instead of `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`

(2) change following properties for eslint configuration file.

```
  rules: {
   "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
  }
```

But Starting from React 17,Dont need to add import React from 'react' and next js as well

Comment: that's right! It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The line below *solved* this problem for me.

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import {css, jsx} from "@emotion/react";
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow as in picture for removing that lint error and adding automatic fix by addin g--fix in package.json

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when you're using JSX syntax in a file that doesn't have React imported at the top.

To fix it, you need to make sure that you import React at the top of the file where you're using JSX. Here's an example:

```
import React from 'react'

function MyComponent() {
  return <div>Hello, world!</div>
}
```

Make sure to add React import at the top of any file that uses JSX.

Answer (score 0):

in babel, add `"runtime": "automatic"` option

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future references you can try this one
The react packages might have not been updated

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

for yarn

```
yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
```

If there is compatibility issues, you can git revert to the previous packages.

Answer (score 0):

A crucial point (and perhaps a simpler solution) here if you're using TypeScript then use the following in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  compilerOptions: {
    ...
    // if you use react-jsx here the import React statement won't be required
    // if you use react here you'll need the import React statement to make TS happy
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated the version of my project's react-scripts by running the below code in the terminal and it worked.

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

Comment: This will not work. Say for example I am getting this issue with react 16 and if i run the cmd with @latest it will install the latest version of react which might be higher than 16.