# 'React' does not work from global scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot figure out what is I'm making wrong. Also I had read a several questions on the SOF, but any of them is do not suits me.

I have a stack of errors:

Line 3:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 4:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 5:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 9:  'ReactDOM' is not defined                no-undef

```js
function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
 
  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

in the top of the file.

Comment: Oh, yes. Typical mistake. Thank you!