# tutorial code -> 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react.js and this is literaly the code provided in the tutorial on their website to make a tic tac toe game. However, when i try and compile, i get -> 'React' must be in scope when using JSX. I have copied and pasted tutorial code. I am currently using vim editor. If there is a better editor to use please suggest!

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}       //onclick button
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [
        {
          squares: Array(9).fill(null)
        }
      ],
      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([
        {
          squares: squares
        }
      ]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    });
  }

  jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0
    });
  }

  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;                //to store history of 
//game
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
      return (
        <li key={move}>
          <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
        </li>
      );
    });

    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = "Winner: " + winner;
    } else {
      status = "Next player: " + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
    }

    return (
        <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{moves}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("root"));

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === 
squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: `import React from 'react'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using class Game extends React.Component you will need the dependency to the included in the file on the top. Also if ReactDOM.render Call is in the same file, you will have to include that dependency too.
Also I hope you have React and ReactDOM dependencies in package.json file.

Put this at the top of the file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: `import` should be lower case, `'react'` and `'react-dom'` should be normal-quoted, not smart quoted.

Comment: Also, we should add `import './index.css';` as well to pick up on the stylesheet they made us add. I don't know why all this is left out from the tutorial.