# Why I can't import Constants from another file in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was practicing React-Routing, I want to separate constants in another file away from my App.js. Basically, these constants are content for my pages that I want to be editable in a separate environment. But after importing them to App.js, it gives error "'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-".
Here is my App.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {Home,About} from "./Constants.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and Constants in Constants.js:

```
const Home = (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

export { Home, About };
```

Comment: Is the error not self explanatory? Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSX gets compiled into `React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgfMAWBMUASB7AtgU2AegTb40QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=), so you need to import React if you are using JSX.

You should also write stateless functional components as functions, instead of as a React element directly.

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

export { Home, About };
```