# get React' must be in scope when using JSX error when import component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing this code and import `React` and `Component` in `app/js` file and also try to import app.js to `index.js`. but I get this `error` ' 'React' must be in scope when using `JSX` in `index.js`

app.js :

```js
import React ,{Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello Ashkan</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app'



ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

I got this error

> ./src/index.js
>     Line 6:'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Comment: React will still need to be imported in `index.js`

Comment: import React from 'react'

import react like this in index.js

Comment: Look at which file the error is from...

Comment: I'm sorry this was my problem.thank for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSX in here (`<App />`):

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Whenever you use JSX React should be in scope.