# How to use JSX in a JSON object

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use JSX in a JSON object but I get this error message 

**'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope**

```
import {Translate} from 'react-localize-redux';
import Translations from '../translations/dashboard';

export default {
  items: [
    {
      name: <Translate id="movie.title" />,
      url: '/dashboard',
      icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    },
  ]
}
```

Please, can someone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 5):

Add `import React from 'react';` at the beginning of the file and make sure filename extension is `.jsx` or `.tsx`;

Comment: Oh god, I totally forgot about the ".tsx"extension. You saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **React** into your file. 
Add `import React from 'react';` at the top 
Your file should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Translate} from 'react-localize-redux';
import Translations from '../translations/dashboard';

export default {
  items: [
    {
      name: <Translate id="movie.title" />,
      url: '/dashboard',
      icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    },
  ]
}
```

**Note:** You may decide to change the extension of the file to `.jsx` or `.tsx` as suggested by @LiJonas