# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope when trying to do it from a index file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to aggregate all imports at one location and then export it for other components to use

I have a src/car folder with car.js and index.js inside it

code inside index.js is as below

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    export {React, ReactDOM}
```

code inside car.js is as below

```
    import * as Wfmimport from './index';

    export class Car extends Wfmimport.React.Component {
      render() {
        return <h2>Hi, I am a Car!</h2>;
      }
    }
```

my src/index.js has following code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as name from './car/car'
import './index.css';



ReactDOM.render(<name.Car />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

when I run the code, I get error "'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope when trying to do it from a index file"

can anyone help me what is that wrong which I am doing?

My goal is to reduce import statements and hence I am trying the above way

Comment: If you change car.js to implicitly import React, what happens then?

Comment: It works in that case, but I am doing the above purposefully for a cause

Comment: try `import * as Name from './car/car'` and in ReactDOM.render change `<name.Car />` to `<Name.Car />`

Comment: @AtinSingh tried your suggestion, It doesn't work, the same problem

Comment: Hmm.. maybe the error is there because There is Wfmimport.React but not React to compile the jsx.

Comment: You can do `import {React, ReactDOM} from "./index"` instead?

Comment: @AtinSingh doing the above works,but the reason I am using wfmimport is intentional as I have a file with 100's of exports and then while importing I don't want to write 100 components in the import line

Comment: okay, i got your point but you need React standalone. You can make it work like this too - `const React = Wfmimport.React;`. This will solve the problem but it makes no sense since you can just import react from react?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)