# React JS Error: 'Component' is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in ReactJS, I prepared the below files:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import InstructorApp from "./component/InstructorApp";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <InstructorApp />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ListCoursesComponent.jsx

```
class ListCoursesComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>All Courses</h3>
        <div className="container">
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Learn Full stack with Spring Boot and Angular</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

InstructorApp.jsx

```
class InstructorApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Instructor Application</h1>
        <ListCoursesComponent />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default InstructorApp;
```

When I am compiling the code, I am getting the below error :

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/component/InstructorApp.jsx
>
> Line 1:29:  'Component' is not defined               no-undef   Line
>   4:7:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX 
>   react/react-in-jsx-scope   Line 5:9:   'React' must be in scope when
>   using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope   Line 6:9:   'React' must be in
>   scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope   Line 6:10: 
>   'ListCoursesComponent' is not defined    react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Please if someone can help me it will be greet.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you write jsx, you need React in scope; meaning you need to `import React from "react"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 5):

You missed to import `Component` from `react` in `InstructorApp` and `ListCoursesComponent` components as mentioned in the error you got also the other **components should be imported too from their location**, your components should be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ListCoursesComponent from './ListCoursesComponent.jsx';

class InstructorApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Instructor Application</h1>
        <ListCoursesComponent />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default InstructorApp;
```

also in `ListCoursesComponent` you missed the import `React`, `Component` and the export statement:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ListCoursesComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>All Courses</h3>
        <div className="container">
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Learn Full stack with Spring Boot and Angular</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListCoursesComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tested your suggestion and i get the below error: 
```
./src/component/InstructorApp.jsx
  Line 8:10:  'ListCoursesComponent' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: I updated as you suggested,  but still having the same error:
./src/component/InstructorApp.jsx
  Line 8:10:  'ListCoursesComponent' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Just noticed the issue, you are not also importing `ListCoursesComponent` component inside `InstructorApp` **Note: that you should change the import based on the location of `ListCoursesComponent` location.**

Comment: i made the change which you mentioned, now i have this error:


./src/component/InstructorApp.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './component/ListCoursesComponent' in 'C:\Users\etamfao\frontend-spring-boot-react-crud-full-stack-with-maven\src\component'

Comment: now it is working, i add another "." as you can see below:
import ListCoursesComponent from "../component/ListCoursesComponent";

Answer (score 1):

The Final solution was: 
In the file : InstructorApp.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ListCoursesComponent from "../component/ListCoursesComponent";

class InstructorApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Instructor Application</h1>
        <ListCoursesComponent />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default InstructorApp;
```