# Getting 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I tried the following code

**person.js**

```
const element = <h1>Hello world</h1>;
export default element;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Person from '../src/person/person';



function Hello() {
  return Person.element;
}



class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Hello></Hello>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But getting the below errors

***work/my-app/src/person/person.js
  3:17  error  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope***

When I changed to a simple hello word as below, then it works fine.

person.js

```
const element = 'hello world';
export default element;
```

I tried  with different ways by checking different forum

1. importing the ReactDom
2. in person.js changed to module.exports=element

Comment: Your imports must be at the very top of your files.

Comment: Both of those should import react, and your imports should go at the top of your file.

Comment: Judging by the other comments, I think that maybe your imports need to be at the very top of the file

Comment: I have updated the question. When I post the question,by mistake App.js file name  has come in between javascript code that  was the reason it was showing the imports in between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of HTML within JS code is known as JSX. The `<h1>...</h1>` is JSX. You need to import `React` before you use JSX. Simply shift the import statements before any use of JSX.

**person.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Person from '../src/person/person';

const element = <h1>Hello world</h1>;
export default element;
```

Comment: I have updated the question. When I post the question,by mistake App.js file name has come in between javascript code that was the reason it was showing the imports in between.

Comment: @user414967 As every other comment and even the other answer has mentioned, you need to import React in all your files that use JSX. **person.js** is not an exception.

Comment: Infact i was trying to avoid the dependency of React. Assume, if this person.js is a third party library, then we cannot import React over there. in such cases, how do we do?

Comment: @user414967 As long as you are using JSX, you will need to import React. So if you don't want to import React, don't use JSX in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import React in every file that exports a component (App in this case).

Comment: I have updated the question. When I post the question,by mistake App.js file name has come in between javascript code that was the reason it was showing the imports in between.

Answer (score 1):

**The latest React 17 Version: No need to include React in the scope**

If you are struggling with ESlint or run-time CRA warnings, follow these temporary steps to fix until CRA v4 is released: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9850