# react must be in scope when using jsx error

Tags: reactjs

Very Simple code , I'hv checked react spelling, ReactDom imported, Please guide me about the error. I am new to the codding world.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Cardlist } from "./components/cardlist/cardlist.component.jsx";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      string: "Hello before",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{this.state.string}</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ string: "After text" })}>
          Change text
        </button>
        <Cardlist name="this was prop" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Cardlist component

```
import react from "react";

export const Cardlist = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>COngratulations</div>;
};
```

Comment: Can you share code for `Cardlist` ?

Comment: I have just edited my question , with cardlist component, Please check. Thanks in advance dipansh

Comment: Can you try changing that `react` to `React` on first line on CardList ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing that `react` to `React` on `first line` on `CardList` ?