# i am facing react must be in scope when using jsx this tyoe of error...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-redux, react-hooks

when i am run npm start in termianl then i am facing this type of error so I have no idea what I do...?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `import * as React from "react"`

Comment: import React  from 'react';

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton), it is not necessary to import React anymore for JSX to work, so [this ESLint rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md) is probably throwing the error, depending on your ESLint configuration.
You can either disable the rule on your configuration file or the ignore file or import React.

```js
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: (Noting that this is version-specific and is no longer required https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Comment: Thanks for noting this. However, depending on the ESLint configuration for their project, there is still the rule requiring this.