# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX error

Tags: reactjs

i`m new in React.I received a file and when i run the code i get this error:

```
'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
```

this is a part of the code:

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Profesor from "./components/Profesor";
import Student from "./components/Student";
import Home from "./components/Home";
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to include react :

```
import React from 'react';
```