# getting error 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope

Tags: reactjs

the code is as follows i am getting error

> " React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope" ***

```
import {BrowserRouter as  Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
        <Router>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path= '/' exact />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
         
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't provided the full code here, I assume that your React import statement is wrong.
Import React on top of your .js file

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score 1):

Error came because you did not import React.

`import react from 'react';`

This import is required under React 17
And no more required since React 17