# Can anyone know a solution for 'React' must be in scope when using JSX?

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm using React and I wanted to start the outside API server but I met a problem.

I can't find a solution for problem on screen below:

[image: React must be in scope using JSX]

The problem happens when I'm trying to start the app using `npm start`.

I already have line `import React from 'react'` on my `index.js`.

I'm trying to start the app using command `npm start`. It was working before, but I installed some things in terminal. Ran command: `npm audit fix --force` to fix some critical problems on terminal.

Comment: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md Also note `npm audit fix --force` makes breaking up- and even down-grades to your dependencies, I would strongly recommend **not** running it unless you're really sure you want that.

Comment: please learn use simple hello world program from react docs, and things will work fine

Comment: maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I just dodged that problem with creating another new project, coppied everything from the old one and it's working, lol.
As like jonrsharpe wrote, do not write npm audit fix --force in terminal if you aren't sure about it.

Piotr