# 'React' is declared but its value is never read in a .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, eslint, importerror

I am working on a React project. Is the React import not necessary for .tsx files? The file is building fine but not reading the React import. Throwing the following error in the screenshot. What could be the issue here?

[image: React is declared but its value is never read]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts": "^19.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids": "^19.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-inputs": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-kanban": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-richtexteditor": "^19.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule": "^19.4.50",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.ts?(x)"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.19",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

'React' import isn't working, want to understand what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `React` variable in your code then do not declare It

and it was never a necessity to add a `React` import when creating a react component.

and import is working it is just showing error because you have declared it but not using it
just remove the line`import React from 'react'`

Comment: It was necessary before the react-jsx `jsx` option

Comment: I meant it in context of the current issue..

Answer (score -1):

In React v17, you no longer need to import `React` to use JSX components.

To disable the eslint error, add the following to your .eslintrc.json:

```json
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
  }
```

Official announcement: https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#eslint

Comment: The OP's error is from TypeScript (`noUnusedLocals`), not ESLint/`eslint-plugin-react` (which is also covered on e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42640636/3001761).